Error :Dockerfile required when specifying --tag
@cloudshell:~/hello-python (hello-python-app)$ gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/hello-python-app/helloyoutube ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) Invalid value for [source]: Dockerfile required when specifying --tag
I tried generating the google submit build, even though the DockerFile is in the current directory, shell is throwing the error?
How can I modify the command to generate a successful build?

I think you must specify the [source] location even if the working directory. Please try gcloud builds submit ${PWD} --tag gcr.io/hello-python-app/helloyoutube

Hey @DazWilkin, tried adding the file path, didn't work.
